# WebClient.DownloadString results in mangled characters due to encoding issues, but the browser is OK

Tags: .net, unicode, utf-8, webclient

The following code:

```
var text = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=au:Freidel_L*&start=0&max_results=20"));
```

results in a variable `text` that contains, among many other things, the string

> "$Îº$-Minkowski space, scalar field, and the issue of Lorentz invariance"

However, when I visit that URL in Firefox, I get

> $κ$-Minkowski space, scalar field, and the issue of Lorentz invariance

which is actually correct. I also tried

```
var data = (new WebClient()).DownloadData("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=au:Freidel_L*&start=0&max_results=20");
var text = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
```

but this gave the same problem.

I'm not sure where the fault lies here. Is the feed lying about being UTF8-encoded, and the browser is smart enough to figure that out, but not `WebClient`? Is the feed properly UTF8-encoded, but `WebClient` is failing in some other way? What can I do to mitigate this?

Comment: `UTF8Encoding.Default` is actually `Encoding.Default`, which is ANSI encoding based by the OS language settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebClient.DownloadString() returns string with peculiar characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716470/webclient-downloadstring-returns-string-with-peculiar-characters)

Answer (score 221, accepted):

It's not lying. You should set the webclient's encoding first before calling DownloadString.

```
using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string s = webClient.DownloadString("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=au:Freidel_L*&start=0&max_results=20");
}
```

As for why your alternative isn't working, it's because the usage is incorrect. Its should be:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Strange that the `WebClient` doesn't use the headers to detect this, but this works perfectly, and between you and @svick, I understand why the other thing I tried was failing miserably as well.

Comment: Works for `UploadString` as well