# Is HttpWebRequest or Webclient faster

Tags: c#, get, httpwebrequest, webclient

I need to GET contents of a specific URL. It's a simple and straightforward task, though I want is as efficient as possible.

Does WebClient or HttpWebRequest take less memory?
Which class will complete the same task faster?
Which class takes less time to initialize?

Comment: "It depends". Why not try it and find out? There are also differences in ease of use, and of capabilities.

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's just the matter of which one is faster. Honestly I don't know how to measure exactly what I mentioned in my questions.

Comment: If you can't measure it, then you don't need to know it. There's no simple concept of "faster". At best, there's "faster in particular circumstances". Basically, don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`WebClient` is just a wrapper around `HttpWebRequest`. Using `WebClient` is potentially *slightly* (on the order of a few milliseconds) slower than using `HttpWebRequest` directly. But that "inefficiency" comes with huge benefits: it requires less code, is easier to use, and you're less likely to make a mistake when using it. Consider, for example, retrieving the text of a Web page using `WebClient`:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var text = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/page.html");
```

Contrast that to `HttpWebRequest`:

```
string text;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/page.html");
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Things get really interesting if you want to download and save to file. With `WebClient`, it's a simple matter of calling `DownloadFile`. With `HttpWebRequest`, you have to create a reading loop, etc. The number of ways you can make a mistake with `HttpWebRequest` is truly astounding. I know 'cause I've made a lot of them.

Now consider downloading two different pages. With `WebClient` you can write:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var page1 = client.DownloadString(page1Url);
var page2 = client.DownloadString(page2Url);
```

Done. With `HttpWebRequest`, you'd have to duplicate the code above, or wrap that code in a method. But if you're going to wrap it in a method, then why not just use `WebClient`, which already does it for you?

When you consider that a request to a fast Web site will probably take on the order of 100 to 500 milliseconds, the few milliseconds' overhead that `WebClient` adds will amount to *at most* single-digit percentage of the total time.

Use `WebClient` for simple things. Only use `HttpWebRequest` if you require the additional low-level control that it offers. Speed considerations among the two are irrelevant.

Comment: I would say the difference in performance is in the orders of microseconds, not milliseconds... Nice answer!

Comment: Pay attention to encoding, WebClient it is easier to use, but it seems from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137165/webclient-downloadstring-results-in-mangled-characters-due-to-encoding-issues-b that you need to know in advance the encoding used.