# c# convert downloaded string with special language chars

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7.1

I'm retrieving from geonames the names of locations (that should have unconventional characters depending by the country): for example:

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?lat=40.826523&lng=26.918055&radius=21&maxRows=24&username=demo

retrieve this:

```
{
    adminCode2: "8632559",
    adminCode1: "59",
    adminName2: "Malkara",
    lng: 26.964775,
    distance: "6.73594",
    countryCode: "TR",
    postalCode: "59300",
    adminName1: "Tekirdağ",
    placeName: "Çavuşköy",
    lat: 40.875728
},
```

and when I download with

```
var json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

I get this:

```
{
    "adminCode2":"8632559",
    "adminCode1":"59",
    "adminName2":"Malkara",
    "lng":26.964775,
    "distance":"6.73594",
    "countryCode":"TR",
    "postalCode":"59300",
    "adminName1":"TekirdaÄŸ",
    "placeName":"Ã‡avuÅŸkÃ¶y",
    "lat":40.875728
},
```

any ideas on how to convert directly all the string to get the right names?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you try to use [encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.encoding?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebClient_Encoding)?

Comment: it worked with https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137997/349045

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add header:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "tr-TR";

client.DownloadString(url);
```