# Getting Gibberish instead of Hebrew when using webclient

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient

I'm trying to use WebClient class to view the content of a hebrew page, but get gibberish instead of Hebrew.

My code is:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "charset=windows-1255");
    string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://hebrew-academy.huji.ac.il/Pages/default.aspx");
}
```

I'm receiving the English content correctly, but the Hebrew content is Gibberish for example:

<title>
׳”׳׳§׳“׳׳™׳” ׳׳׳©׳•׳ ׳”׳¢׳‘׳¨׳™׳× ג€“ ׳“׳£ ׳”׳‘׳™׳×</title>

Does anyone knows how to get the hebrew content correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET / C# WebClient.DownloadString() returns string with perculiar characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716470/asp-net-c-sharp-webclient-downloadstring-returns-string-with-perculiar-chara)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That page is transmitted as UTF-8, so you should be interpreting it as UTF-8, not as Windows-1255. [Do this by setting `WebClient.Encoding` to `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716548/139010)

Comment: Same result when I use: webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "utf-8");

Comment: [`Content-Type` when used as a request header only specifies the content type of data being sent in the request, for POST and PUT.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) See my edit for the fix.