# C# - WebClient.DownloadString does not detect response encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient, content-type

As I was working with `WebClient` class, I noticed that a simple call like this

```
string downloadedString = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://whatever");
```

produced a string using an incorrect encoding, even though the response contained a proper `Content-Type` header `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

When I looked at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,3688e959a4f704f8) I found out that `DownloadString` doesn't look at the response headers at all. Instead it uses `request.ContentType` and if the charset is not present there, it uses the `Encoding` property (which has to be set beforehand, otherwise it will be system's default).

It seems weird that we have to specifically tell the `WebClient` object which encoding to use before sending the request (by adding a `Content-Type` header or setting encoding directly). It becomes pointless to use `DownloadString`: if we want the right encoding, we have to use `DownloadData` or plain old `WebRequest` and write code that parses response headers manually in order to get the correct response string.

Does anyone know the reason for such behavior?
Is there a better way in .NET to properly download HTTP string response, than manually parsing response `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 1):

The WebClient [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/3688e959a4f704f8.html) seems to indicate that when you call `DownloadString` it uses the *request* content type as the encoding for the *response*, which is weird, and probably a bug.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716470/webclient-downloadstring-returns-string-with-peculiar-characters#answer-30049848) to a similar question. It includes code that uses `DownloadData` to get the response, then converts it to a string using the correct encoding, as specified in the response's `Content-Type` header.