# Unparseable StackExchange API response

Tags: c#, webclient, stackexchange-api, downloadstring

I've written a small program to analyze my profile data from the StackExchange API, but the api returns unparse-/unreadable data to me.

**Data received:** (self downloaded using c#)

> \u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0mRMo�0\f�/:�d$�c˱�'�^{/\u0006��\u0018G�>\I��\u0015���\u0004݀�D>�GR�L'���o��\u0004�G���%JP\u001c����-��Em>0���X�bm~�\u0018tk��\u0014�M]r�dLG�v0~Fj=���1\u00031I�>kTRA\"(/+.����;Nl\u0018�?h�\u0014��P藄�X�aL��w���#�3\u0002��+�\u007f���\u0010���\u000f�p�]��v\u007f���\t��ڧ�\nf��״\u0018\u0014eƺ�_��1x#j^-�c� � AX\t���\u001aT��@qj\u001aU7�����\u0014\"\a^\b�#\u001e��QG��%�y�\t�ח������q00K\av\u0011{ظ���\u0005\"\u001d+|\u007f���'�\u0016~��8\u007f�\u0001-h�]O\u007fV�o\u007f\u0001~Y\u0003��\u0002\0\0

**Data wanted:** (copy-pasted from my browser)

> {"items":[{"badge_counts",{"bronze":987,"silver":654,"gold":321},"account_id":123456789,"is_employee":false,"last_modified_date":1250612752,"last_access_date":1250540770,"age":0,"reputation_change_year":987,"reputation_change_quarter":654,"reputation_change_month":321,"reputation_change_week":98,"reputation_change_day":76,"reputation":9876,"creation_date":1109670518,"user_type":"registered","user_id":123456789,"accept_rate":0,"location":"Australia","website_url":"http://example.org","link":"http://example.org/username","profile_image":"http://example.org/username/icon.png","display_name":"username"}],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":300}

I've written this (extension) method to download a string from the internet:

```
public static string DownloadString(this string link)
{
    WebClient wc = null;
    string s = null;
    try
    {
        wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        s = wc.DownloadString(link);
        return s;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (wc != null)
        {
            wc.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've then searched the internet and found a method for downloading strings, using some other tactics:

```
public string DownloadString2(string link)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Stream data = client.OpenRead(link);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();
    return s;
}
```

But both methods return the same (unread-/unparseable) data.

How can I get readable data from the API? Is there anything missing?

Comment: FWIW, `try{}finally{}` blocks without `catch{}` blocks are perfectly valid, if all you're doing is rethrowing the exception.

Comment: What is the URL you are accessing?

Comment: @PatrickHofman http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/4000926?site=stackoverflow

Comment: @JamesThorpe just added the `throw` section for debugging/error search, normally empty --- but thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me that the output is compressed. You could use the `GZipStream` which can be found in `System.IO.Compression` in order to decompress the bytes.

```
public static string DownloadString(this string link)
{
    WebClient wc = null;
    try
    {
        wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] b = wc.DownloadData(link);

        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream g = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(b), CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            g.CopyTo(output);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (wc != null)
        {
            wc.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as you can see - the encoding you were using is wrong -

[image]