# Android YouTube V3 API not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am hitting the following url from my android device.

URL : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=MY_KEY&channelId=UCoWgc1mqe-bcfb_lem7EyOg&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50

Response: ������������������]�r�8�}ϯ@e?䋕�}ɗ    j����%OO(@�`q3���*b�a"�g�o�K��%Y]�em�,uGd8m�ātu��]������/�c���W�_����`B���M��;v�������q:��fA�[8KR�����lZ?[t]�඘JL���`�������G1����h䬑��T[}E�y�]qt�_xl��.��e/v�o���H

For getting the YouTube Videos List.It was working fine before but sometimes its response is not valid while hitting from browsers it works well.

Please help me !!

Comment: Inspect it with a tool like `Fiddler` or `Wireshark` in order to inspect the content-encoding http header. The first thing that comes in my mind is, that the response you get might be compressed into `gzip`, `bzip` or `deflate`. In this case you have to decompress it like you have to do it with a `zip` file. If the response is compressed you have to decompress it first in your app.

Comment: Why it was working before ? and also how it is working on browsers ? My apps are on playstore and they were working fine. Suddenly apps stops working and in logs above stupid thing is showing with 200 response code.

Comment: please read my comment again... Please provide the value of the `Content-Encoding` header of the response in order to help you.

Comment: the browser do automatically decode the value, these are Specialized for this.

Comment: X-Origin
application/json; charset=UTF-8
 gzip
 nosniff
 SAMEORIGIN
 1; mode=block
 GSE
 quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
 chunked

These values are going in the header

Comment: as you can see, your response was compressed using `gzip`. Just decompress it and you have the Jason data you wanted.

Comment: if this is problem why YouTube change response and they have not notified us

Comment: Now i have to code it and upload a new build ..its means i will lost my thousands of users

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution i was using the loop j library (for http request) old version

just changes

compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'

to

compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please see my related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418076/unparseable-stackexchange-api-response) (but in `C#`) and the answers on it in order to understand what I mean. Then you have to search example for`decompress gzip android` and look at the existing resources to accomplish this.

Please keep in mind, that the API does not always send the response in gzip-format or not. So please do a check if the response is really in gzip.

For the plain decompression you can use the following method:

```
public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis, BUFFER_SIZE);
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
        s.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    gis.close();
    bis.close();
    return s.toString();
}
```

(this code was taken from [Vyshnavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010020))