# C# WebClient doesn't return UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, webclient

Hey :) I'm trying really hard to make WebClient return me UTF-8. But when sub should return something like `Ä` it's more a `E` or so I think.

Gave a lot of workarounds a try, but It won't work.

```
private string translate(string input, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "UTF-8");
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var data = wc.DownloadData(url);
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    //string result = wc.DownloadString(url);
    int start = result.IndexOf("result_box");
    string sub = result.Substring(start);
    sub = sub.Substring(0, sub.IndexOf("</span>"));
    start = sub.LastIndexOf(">");
    sub = sub.Substring(start + 1);
    return sub;
}
```

Comment: please give inputs (`input` and `languagePair`)

Comment: example input: would, lp: en|de returns w?rde instead of würde

Comment: Hello, can you change your title that is misleading ! WebClient can read UTF-8 ! Your problem is linked to Google translate and not to WebClient. It would be appropriate to change your title !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google simply ignores encoding sent in `AcceptCharset` headers and returns response in `ISO-8859-1`, as you can see from shortened response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 64202

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
```

Therefore when you decode response using UTF-8 encoding, you get invalid characters. If you want just to make it work quickly, I have found that when `User-Agent` header is added to request, Google returns response in UTF-8 and you can leave rest of code unmodified:

```
private static string translate(string input, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "utf-8");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0");
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string result = wc.DownloadString(url);
    int start = result.IndexOf("result_box");
    string sub = result.Substring(start);
    sub = sub.Substring(0, sub.IndexOf("</span>"));
    start = sub.LastIndexOf(">");
    sub = sub.Substring(start + 1);
    return sub;
}
```

Better solution is to detect encoding used in response and use it for decoding. `WebClient` does not have this detection built-in, so you can either use solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049848/1286670) or use `HttpClient` instead, which does this for you automatically:

```
private static async Task<string> translate(string input, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    using (var hc = new HttpClient())
    {
        var result = await hc.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        int start = result.IndexOf("result_box");
        string sub = result.Substring(start);
        sub = sub.Substring(0, sub.IndexOf("</span>"));
        start = sub.LastIndexOf(">");
        sub = sub.Substring(start + 1);
        return sub;
    }
}
```

Also please note that Google has [Translation API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/translate/v2), which might be better to use rather than parsing translation from HTML page.