# C# - How to insert data from web service (XML) that contains Unicode characters to DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, dataset, odata

I am trying to read from web service (ODATA) an XML and save the data at DataSet.
The problem is that there are Unicode characters I can not read.

My code looks like that:

```
        String URLString = "SomeUrl";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(URLString);
```

What is the simplest way to get the data with the Unicode characters and save it in DataSet?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with 'Unicode characters I can not read'? What error do you get?

Comment: @Hintham The purpose is that it's reading, for example, a text in Hebrew (in that case) as âìéåï instead of בדיקה.
There is encoding problem I think, that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Net doesn't accept unicode definition in first line of the xml.  So you need to skip the first line.  So I usually use followng : StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Unicode); reader.ReadLine(); ds.ReadXml(reader);

Comment: We really need a [mcve] to answer this question property.  The [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataSet.cs,2150) shows that `DataSet` uses the obsolete `XmlTextReader` to download the XML.  It wouldn't surprise me if it got the encoding wrong.

Comment: Try passing the `XmlReader` returned by [`XmlReader.Create(URLString)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf(v=vs.110).aspx) into [`DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6swf149(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if that fixes the problem.  Alternatively, you could try downloading the manually as a string using the newer `HttpClient` or `WebClientExtensions.DownloadStringAwareOfEncoding()` from [WebClient.DownloadString() returns string with peculiar characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049848/3744182).